# Queries on Śrī Lalitā Sahasranāma Phalaśruti

Tags: worship, agamas, lalita

As per Śrī Lalitā Sahasranāma Phalaśruti:

> [13] &   [14]   The supreme puṇya which results from a repetition of a
> single name of the secret Sahasranāma. The accumulated sins, of him
> who repeats at least a single name of this secret Sahasranāma, are all
> destroyed. There is no doubt in this.
>
> [15]   All sins of omission of prescribed daily duties and commission
> of prohibited actions, are surely destroyed. Why describe in so many
> words? Listen, O Pot-Born one:
>
> [16]   No person, in all the fourteen worlds, is capable of committing
> a sin which cannot be removed by a single name in this Sahasranāma
> which is the antidote of all sins

Quoted from: [Phalaśruti mentioned here](http://shaktisadhana.50megs.com/Newhomepage/sadhana/lallithasahasranama/phalasruti.html).

As per [16], if with a single name so many sins can be removed then there should not be any obstacles and suffering left in my life.

It is a beautiful stotra of Goddess and I really love it. I chant it daily however in almost all the stotras, the Phal that is described seems to be not working in present times.

I want to know whether these statements are valid in Kaliyuga also. Apart from devotion and faith, is there any specific method for chanting Sahasranāma which I am not doing and therefore not getting results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [KAmAkotimanadali page](http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=137&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) tries to determine "lalitA sahasranAma - adhikAra nirNaya".

That means trying to determine who all are competent to recite the stotram. That means not all are competent to start with.

> Bhagavan Hayagriva clearly mentions the qualification required for the
>   recitation/practice of Sri Lalita Sahasranama in the pUrva pIThikA of
>   the Sahasranama.
>
> Qualification
>
> 1. The Sahasranama is never to be given to a one who is a crook, who finds pleasure in other’s misery and one who has no faith in
>      Amba/Guru. Such people are not qualified to recite this Sahasranama.
> 2. Now, let’s say the person has overcome all these qualities. Is that sufficient? No! Bhagavan further says - shrImAtR^ibhaktiyuktAya - the
>      person should be devoted to Sri Lalita. One can be a devotee of Sri
>      Shiva, Sri Ganesha, Sri Vishnu or even of other forms like Sri Kali or
>      Sri Durga. But a person whose chief upAsyA is Sri LalitAmbikA, he
>      alone is qualified to recite this Sahasranama.
> 3. **Ok! We have a person who is good, and is also devoted to Sri Lalita. Is that sufficient? Not again!** Bhagavan says:
>      shrIvidyArAjavedine - **one who has been initiated into Srividya - he
>      alone is qualified to recite this Sahasranama.** Some assume that
>      Srividya here can be bAla, panchadashi or Shodashi, but there is no
>      room for doubt here. **Srividya here is simply Panchadashi**. The question
>      of Shodashi does not arise at all as Shodashi includes Panchadashi in
>      itself and hence holds good without a doubt. bAlA upAsakas are
>      eligible to recite bAlA sahasranAma but not lalitA sahasranAma.

Now, you have clarified to me elsewhere, in some comments,  that you are not initiated  and in particular that you do not have a Sri VidyA DikshA. So, it seems that you are not yet competent to recite the stotram.

And that's why instead of all the sincere efforts you are failing to get the benefits which the Phalasruti mentions.

Now, that makes Goddess really concerned for you. Because you are a devotee but you are devoid of the right guidance. And, i think, that's why you got that dream where you got to know, for the first time in your life, about the Panchadashi.

If you ask me to interpret the dream, then i'll say, Goddess is simply asking you to take a Sri VidyA dikshA. So, that you may become competent to recite the stotram which you love so much.

And, generally speaking, in all cases DikshA is the first thing to be done. It is the first step towards spiritual progress. And all the other things come after that.

This is how Lord Shiva condemns the act of remaining uninitiated:

> AdikshitA ye kurvanti japapujAdikAh kriyAha |
>  Na phalanti priye
>   teshAm shilAyAmupta vijavat ||
>
> ......
>
> [Lord Shiva says to Sri Devi] Whatever a person, who is not initiated,
>   does, whether it is PujA (worship) or Japa (chanting) or any other religious acts, proves abortive just like seeds sown on stones.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 14.96**

That article i quoted also lists a warning for those who recite the stotram but who are not yet qualified.

> **The Phalasruti says that a person without the said qualification, who
>   recites the Sahasranama, attracts Yogini Shapa - curse from the
>   Yoginis. The Sahasranama is infinitely powerful and using it without
>   the said preparation blows up one’s energy network**. As Yoginis are
>   nothing but the various energies in the body, yogini shApa means
>   energy disturbances in the body which manifest as various physical,
>   emotional and intellectual disorders.

Although it might not be helpful for your case, still i am quoting the rules for reading the stotram:

> Sri Lalita Sahasranama is both a Stotra and a mAlA mantra. If you
>   choose to recite it as a Stotra, recite it vocally, at an even pace,
>   without shaking one’s head, hands, legs or engaging in other
>   activities during the recitation. If recited as a mAlA mantra, one
>   needs to perform RishyAdi nyAsa, panchapUja, recite the dhyAna Shloka,
>   show the relevant Mudras if directed by the Guru and then begin
>   reciting the Mantra with a chant of Pranava. The recitation of Pranava
>   is based on one’s varNa. This has been discussed at length by Sri
>   Bhaskararaya in Saubhagya Bhaskara. When recited as a mantra, it can
>   be repeated mentally. Though some perform a purashcharana of the
>   Sahasranama, I don’t see any need for the same. As only Srividya
>   Upasakas are permitted to recite the Sahasranama, it comes without
>   saying that they have the mUla mantra which requires purashcharana and
>   not the Sahasranama. There are several Sahasranamas which come with
>   purashcharana instructions. But the fact that Sri Lalita Sahasranama
>   does not come with any such instruction points towards the necessity
>   of Upasana of Srividya mantra along with the Sahasranama for full
>   result.
>
> The three prescribed duties for a Srividya Upasaka are:
>
> 1. Chakrarajarchana
> 2. Srividya Japa
> 3. Sahasranama Japa

But you need not worry because you already got Bhakti for Goddess. So, you will certainly get the GUru and desired results sooner or later.

> Bhakti is already a prescribed qualification to even take up the
>   recitation of the Sahasranama. Amba has not been declared
>   mantravashyA, tantravashyA, yajnavashyA etc. but only as BhaktivashyA.
>   The only sure way to win her infinite and unconditional grace is by
>   Bhakti, which leads one to a state where the truth of Amba as the self
>   is comprehended. As the Sahasranama also states - nAmapArAyaNaprItA,
>   what better way to please Amba than by reciting the thousand names
>   with a sense of overflowing love for the Supreme Mother of the
>   universe? rAga or love for worldly objects leads to bondage. But the
>   same love or anuraga, when turned towards Amba becomes Bhakti and
>   leads to liberation. parAnukraktirIshware bhaktiH. Every name recited
>   should be a call to Amba, lifting our arms - asking her to lift us up
>   in her arms. Every name recited should be a prostration at her feet,
>   surrendering the self to her. Every name recited should be an
>   indication of unbearable grief due to separation from Amba. Every name
>   should be an outcry of unfathomable joy arising out of her proximity
>   that is felt with the recitation of every name!

So, i feel the fact that you are not initiated yet and also the fact that you are not initiated into Sri VidyA yet are apparently the reasons for your perceived failures.

Comment: The last quote about worship and chanting doesn't make any sense, does it? Is that quote about special worship and special kind of chanting like Purascharana or regular chanting?

Comment: It makes sense to me. If you go to any Guru Satsangs they will also say the same. It's something which is repeated everywhere in scriptures. So, it's a fact that is quite well-known i guess. Elsewhere (in Matrika Bheda) Lord Shiva says the kundalini sleeps perpetually till the time Diksha happens and then it wakes up. So, this is the very first step for spiritual progress. Till the time the Kundalini sleeps there is no way to move it upwards towards the crown chakra which is the seat of Parashiva and which is the ultimate goal of Tantra and Yoga. So, what the given verse says is- Without *

Comment: ...Diksha all other spiritual acts are fruitless. But nothing can not be entirely fruitless. It is not so either in this case too. For eg because of OP's sincere efforts he got the guidance of what to do next through a dream. @ChinmaySarupria

Comment: @Rickross Thanks for the answer. I doubt the third point mentioned in Qualification. Stotra is a Prayer not a Mantra. It does not involve intricacies like Mantra. It is the same as Hanuman Chalisa and other Stotras. Prayer does not require Initiation. Many have recommended chanting Sahasranaam alone if you have not taken Diksha. But still I consider your point, let me clarify further below.

Comment: @Rickross Now here I want to mention two points: (1) A Paramhansa saint advised me to chant Sahasranaam. But before he advised me, Goddess started appearing me in dreams but she did not say anything that time till the time I purchased Sahsranaam book. Later this saint asked me to chant Sahasranaam (2) When I started Sahasranaam, in the dream someone told me to recite Panchdasi and Trishati as well.

Comment: This stotram can be taken as both a mantra and a nama stotra. The stotras which have Rishyadi Viniyogah, Karanga Nyasas, Pancha puja are no way different from Mantras. Hanuman chalisa etc are different. They were written so that common man can benefit. Now, if u want such stotras for Goddess then there are plenty i guess (Rajarajeswari Stuti, Lalita Stava Raja, Lalita Panchartnam etc). So instead of reading Sahsranama u can read them. Lalita panchavimsati nama stotram is also there. @RKh

Comment: It's ok. Do not worry about the warnings. Try taking mantra from your Guru and everything will be alright. But personally i feel the fact that you are not initiated yet is the reason for your failures. @RKh

Comment: @Rickross Its OK what you have written citing from scriptures. Scriptures are authority. But as I wrote in another post, unless a Guru is competent, who knows in and out of Sri Vidya, Diksha is of no use. So it is better for me to pray to Goddess to send such a Guru.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Also after initiation, disciples can not criticize Guru, God and Scriptures. In this case you want me to discuss whether what Lord Shiva (who is the only and Adi Guru) says makes any sense or not? Now, that is some discussion i should never indulge in.

Comment: @RKh It's ok. It's ur choice.

Comment: @Rickross I just thought. I chanted other Stotras like Durga Ashtotara, Dwadashmala and other. Leaving Lalita Sahasranaam apart, neither of the above Stotras seemed to be work. I chanted with full devotion for nine years. Even today I have seen even Hanuman Chalisa proving ineffective for people suffering from negative energies. It seems these prayers are also giving results to only 5-10% of people.

Comment: @RKh I know what u mean. But then also my argument will be that you are not initiated that's why. See the verse i gave by Lord Shiva. He is saying exactly the same thing. Now even after initiation things will not start working like magic. But initiation is the very first step. It is always recommended. It is analogous to taking admission in school/college.

Comment: @Rickross I am saying about other Stotras where initiation is not required.

Comment: @RKh You are not understanding my point. Even though Hanuman Chalisa etc won't require initiation but a Guru Diksha always helps. It is said without Guru Diksha a man is just like an animal. Animal in the sense -impure. Also there are rules for reciting stotrams too. You mite not be knowing them. Like adding pranava (OM) to stotrams at certain points. Also you chant stotras with your tongue (speech). Do u know how to do mukha sodhana (purification of mouth)? There are mantras for that. Since most of us don't know such rules we rely upon devotion prayers etc.

Comment: @Rickross OK.....

Comment: Rkh i will post soon

Comment: @Rickross Is there  a way for one not having to get initiated and yet still recieve the blessings of Devi?

Comment: I think most will say chant Lalita Lalita.. But then Goddess will ask you- " if you are my devotee then why are u not following my orders? I have created this Guru-Shisya tradition. Then what stops you from following it?" Guru Diksha is the first step for all kinds of spiritual activities. And i don't think there is any alternative or shortcut for it. @Vick

Answer (score 0):

**What does one have to do to get the fruits of repeating some scriptural texts?**

The answer is that one has to attain mental purity.

> For the attainment of **mental purity**, spiritual aspirants (Yogins)
> perform action devoid of attachment, with their body, mind, intellect
> or even merely with the senses.

**Gita 5.11**

**What happens when one has attained mental purity?**

> Whoever, being engaged to me solely, engage themselves always in
> contemplation and worship of Me - to such ever steadfast devotees I
> ensure the procurement of all their wants (salvation) and the
> preservation of their assets (worldly interests).

**Gita 9.22**

**What can one conclude if one has not been granted one's prayer even after repeating some scripture for many years?**

One can conclude that one has not attained the level of mental purity that is necessary for God to grant the prayers.

**Doesn't one attain mental purity by repeating Lalita Sahasranama?**

Yes, it happens but very slowly. One has to take initiation from a competent Guru to hasten the process. A brief description of how a mantra taken from a Guru works is given below.

> From another point of view, **a mantra gains spiritual potency through
> many years of being associated with holy men who have repeated it and
> attained realization through it.** The concept of the mantra is based on
> the psychological fact that much of our thinking depends on auditory
> symbols. Repetition of the mantra creates a chain of thought which
> induces the mind with the thought of God, and this is the aim of all
> spiritual practices. ................. Every Vedic mantra has a rishi
> who first intuited it, a particular metre in which it is composed, and
> a deity to whom it is addressed. In Tantric mantras the most important
> element is the vija, a sacred syllable considered to be charged with
> spiritual potency, as also Shakti or power and a kilaka, a pillar
> (inner syllables on which the mantra rests.) All the letters of the
> Sanskrit alphabets are considered as different matrikas, minor deities
> around the main deity. **The mantra is charged with a special potency,
> so much so that the Tantrikas believe that when offerings are made to
> the deity with the appropriate mantras, the deity accepts them
> immediately.**

**Meditation and other spiritual disciplines by Swami Swahananda**

Answer (score 0):

4-11-2021 07:01:32

Happy Deepavali to all of you .

Devotion is the supreme practice- not just outer rituals and "mechanical procedures".

From the above:

" 3.Ok! We have a person who is good, and is also devoted to Sri Lalita. Is that sufficient? Not again! Bhagavan says: shrIvidyArAjavedine - one who has been initiated into Srividya - he alone is qualified to recite this Sahasranama ."

It depends on your understanding about Lalitaa - but even mechanical devotion is a starting point .
But anyone who has faith and devotion to Lalitaa can also chant the Lalitaa Sahasranama  - it is not the exclusive right of "initiates alone".
Somewhere in the Lalitopakhyana it says that even if you cannot do the rituals etc. just chanting the Lalitaa Sahasranama with devotion once is beneficial . Of course , then when you gain more traction - you can let Lalitaa show the way .

In the Lalitaa Trishatii Stotra Agastya was still feeling unfulfilled or felt something was missing even after all  the "traditional initiations, rituals and ritual explanations along with having received the Lalitaa Sahasranama from Hayagriva".
His devotion to Lalitaa was of such quality that even after the super secret Lalita Sahasranama - Agastya still felt unfulfilled-something missing . Hayagriva was reluctant and did not want to reveal the Trishatii to Agastya because Hayagriva was told to keep it secret ! IT WAS AGASTYA'S DEVOTION TO LALITAA AND HOLDING HAYAGRIVA'S FEET FOR THREE YEARS - ultimately Lalitaa and Kamesvara appeared and Lalitaa commanded Hayagriva to reveal the Trishatii to devoted Agastya .

One name  from the Lalitaa Trishatii has ten million times more phala than the entire Lalitaa Sahasranama together . I am sure you are acquainted with the Lalitaa Trishatii Stotra .

The Yoginis curse does not scare me one bit - the Yoginis will have to bow down to Lalitaa Trishatii .

Please don't give the impression that "Lalitaa is the exclusive property of so-called initiates etc".

4-11-2021 07:13:39