Benefits of Lalita Sahasranama
What does the Brahmanda Purana say about the benefits and fruits of chanting the Lalita Sahasranama? Are there any formalities to do the sadhana ? Please share some knowledge in this regard. Thank you.

Seems like initiation is required for Ma Lalitā Sahasranāma. Not sure about any scripture references of this information.

Does this help? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21915/34973

Since I cannot locate Lalitha Sahasranama in Brahmanda Purana, I am quoting the benefits of reciting Lalitha Sahasranama from Narada Purana:

From Book I, Chapter 89

This the divine thousand names of Goddess Lalita have been narrated. They afford the achievement of all objects. They yield the
benefit of four fold aims of life.

He who repeats these names every day at dawn with pure mind, becomes a Yogin, a knower of Brahman, a Siva Yogin and a knower of
self.


166 - 167. He who repeats twice every day gains longevity, health and
riches. Certainly, the Sadhaka invariably attains popularity among the
people and the power of attracting women and kings. By repeating
thrice evrery day man keeps the entire universe subservient.

By repeating it four times his wish becomes always fruitful. It can be applied in practical use. It shall protect the worlds.

By its repetition for five times a day men, women, kings, animals and gods with all their heart round the goddess resort to the Sadhaka.

By repeating this six times the Sadhaka shall be identical with the goddess. By the grace of the goddess all Siddhis occur to him.

Through the repetition for seven times a day he destroys enemies, ailments, evil spirits and epileptic fits. Repeating this eight times
a day man becomes capable of restraining kings and blessing them.

By repeating this nine times a day he becomes as resplendent as Manmatha. He makes the earth agitated. In order to achieve fluency of
speech, good fortune and splendour one should recite this ten times a
day.

By repeating this eleven times a day he becomes one shall attain all prosperities. The whole universe will be subservient to him.
Repeating this twelve times a day, a man becomes comparable to Siva by
means of his Siddhis.

By repeating this thirteen times a day man shall become successful all round and happy. By repeating this fourteen times a day
all desired things are obtained. There will be all round
auspiciousness.

By repeating this fifteen times a day, man shall without the least effort attain his desires. By repeating this sixteen times a
day, man becomes Maheswara directly.

He will be competent to create, sustain and annihilate the universe. He who repeats the hymn for forty days or at least a month,
shall truly attain whatever he desires.

This is in accordance with Siva's words...



